# Message: mkdir(): Permission denied AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, mkdir, amazon-ec2

I am getting the following error in my code.

> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied

I have tried other solutions which i found in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and following commands:

```
$ ls -ald /var/www                              
drwxrwsr-x 7 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:58 /var/www
$ ls -ald /var/www/html
drwxrwsr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 26 10:02 /var/www/html
$
```

I referred below document of AWS
[AWS User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

**Update:-**
I can create it from command line. Problem is when i execute my php code i am getting this error.

Answer (score 6):

Which user are you logged in as (find out with `whoami`).  The user and group of these directories are `root` and there is no write permission for "other".

Possible solutions:

- Use `sudo` in front of the command to execute `mkdir` as root
- Change owner / group to allow your user / group write permission using `chown` / `chgrp`